# Ngx-datatable material form fields inside row details

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-datatable

Hello I am trying to add mat form fields inside my row details from ngx datatable.
Normal inputs are working fine, but a mat-select causes my row to not expand. 
It works for this:

But as soon as i put another input field, the rows are not expanding anymore. How can i solve this?

```
<ngx-datatable
    #myTable
    class="material"
    [columnMode]="'flex'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [rows]="details"
    [rowClass]="getRowClass"
    [selectionType]="'single'"
    (select)='onSelect($event)'>
    <ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="'auto'" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
      <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
        <div style="padding-left:35px;" layout="column" layout-wrap>

          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Example</mat-label>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.Omschrijving" required>
            <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let groep of metaData.GevaarGroepen" [value]="groep">
                {{groep.Omschrijving}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Example</mat-label>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.Volgnummer" required>
            <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <!-- IF I ADD THIS OR MORE FORM FIELDS, THE ROWS ARE NOT EXPANDING ANYMORE
             <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Example</mat-label>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.ENa" required>
            <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field> -->
      </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

Comment: I tried to play around with ngx-datatable a day ago and added mat-input and mat-select fields and it was working fine. Check this if it's helpful: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/immad-hamid/masterFormDemo/68ee490efbc9d51efe5fecf3c559bdd70b3272e9/src/app/views/master-form/detail/detail.component.html

Comment: and also check is question at stackoverflow, it's seem like a same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104782/ngx-datatable-detail-row-not-expanding?rq=1

Comment: If i delete the <mat-error> tag it is working fine